# No VSFTP Service

Tags: 14.04, services, vsftpd

Please know I am but a beginner.

I am having trouble installing a VSFTPD server on my computer.
My issue is when I ask for service vsftpd, it doesn't recognize it as a service.

```
[username]@[computer name]:~$ sudo service vsftpd

vsftpd: unrecognized service
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it.
Many thanks,
Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start `vsftpd`, you need to run -

`sudo service vsftpd start`

instead of -

`sudo service vsftpd`

Comment: [username]@[computer name]:~$ sudo service vsftp start
vsftp: unrecognized service

Comment: `vsftpd` with a **d** at the end

Comment: [username]@[computer name]:~$ sudo service vsftpd start
start: Job is already running: vsftpd
[username]@[computer name]:~$ sudo service vsftpd
vsftpd: unrecognized service

Comment: That means it is already running. Check with `sudo service vsftpd status`

Comment: [username]@[computer name]:~$ sudo service vsftpd status
vsftpd start/running, process 1026
thanks!